# Strange behavior with function that converts a vector2 to an angle in degrees

Tags: c++, vector, angle

I am attempting to get a gun to rotate around the player based on a vector2 input

if the y component of the vector is positive it works perfectly as you can see here

[Working as intended (Ignore my placeholder graphics)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LK3DU.png)

if the y component is negative however, it returns the same value as if the y value was positive

[Not working as intended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHtx9.png)

I'm sure this has to do with the equation I'm using, in particular the fact that the y component is removed from the equation when multiplied by the y component in my base vector, but other methods I've used only make things worse, usually causing the gun to not rotate at all while the y value is negative.

```
static u16 vector2To512Ang(vector2 v) {
    // Avoid division by zero
    if (v.getMagnitude() == 0) 
        return 0;
    
    // Base vector
    vector2 b = {1, 0};
    
    float angle = acos((v.x * b.x + v.y * b.y)/abs(v.getMagnitude())) * 57.2957795131f;
    
    // Convert to scale of 0-512
    return (angle * 512) / 360;
}
```

To clear up any questions

1. The scale of the output is weird because I'm working with old hardware and it needs a range of 0-512. Removing this scaling results in the same issue so that isn't the problem
2. The multiplication by 57.2957795131 is the same as 180 / PI precomputed and is done to convert from radians to degrees

Comment: Let the compiler do 180/Pi for you. It will be calculated at compile time, so you have no performance loss. But your code will be more understandable. Everyone knows 180/Pi, nobody knows 57.29.

Comment: If you want to scale to 512, 512/(2*Pi) would be even more comprehensive. Why scale to 360 first, just to scale to 512?

Comment: I did it like that because I'm not super familiar with radians. I also am not super familiar with C++ and I wasn't aware that the compiler would automatically do those operations

Comment: I don't follow the calcuation for the angle. Wouldn't `float angle = atan2(v.y, v.x);` be better? (`*180/ M_PI` for degrees)

Comment: That does work but still doesn't solve the problem of the angle being incorrect when y is negative. The angle output is now always zero if y is negative.

Comment: If you want only positive angles: `float angle = atan2(v.y, v.x); if(angle < 0.) angle += 2. * M_PI;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure what you're after but I think you want the angle between `v.x` and `v.y` scaled to `0-512`. In that case:

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <numbers>

// ...

float angle = std::atan2(v.y, v.x);
if(angle < 0.) angle += 2 * std::numbers::pi_v<float>;
return angle * 512 / (2 * std::numbers::pi_v<float>);
// return angle * 256 / std::numbers::pi_v<float>;
```